# How to implement optimistic locking on AWS S3 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, versioning, optimistic-locking, amazon-s3

I am implementing a database on Amazon S3 and need concurrent access to my index objects (implemented as S3 objects), so I am looking for a way to implement optimistic locking on S3 objects.

My initial thoughts are to utilize the [S3 versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Versioning.html) mechanism and only update an index object (with a PUT operation) when the object version matches the version when I read it. However, based on the S3 documentation, it seems like S3 versioning does not support this functionality: a PUT cannot be conditioned on a specific version, and always update the latest version of the object.

My question is:

1. Is it possible to implement such optimistic locking using S3 versioning (It seems not because of the lack of PUT conditioned on version numbers)?
2. If 1 is not possible, can I implement it using my own versioning (version number kept as S3 object tags, or other object metadata) -- This may also require object put/update conditioned on metadata values.
3. If both 1 and 2 are not possible, do I have to introduce an external mechanism (e.g., Zookeeper or other distributed locking) to implement concurrent access on S3 objects? What is the best practice of doing it? I considered using separate lock objects (implemented as S3 objects) to indicate if an index is locked, but this scheme has certain disadvantages.

I realized similar questions have been asked before, e.g., this, ([Is there optimistic locking in AWS S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618680/is-there-optimistic-locking-in-aws-s3)). However, since S3 now adopts a new strong consistency model (for both write, overwrite, list and delete), the previous answers no longer seem valid.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this by simply using AWS S3 only.

You can implement the following workaround to achieve this:

- You can maintain a lock variable in AWS DynamoDB or AWS SSM Parameter Store (to save money) that can be made TRUE/FALSE during PUT operation.
- You can enable versioning on the S3 bucket and maintain the version to be read for all read operations in AWS DynamoDB or AWS SSM Parameter Store (to save money) and update that version after a successful PUT operation. You can also achieve this by not enabling the versioning on S3 and creating a new object by appending the version number in the key name as a suffix instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about the below approach?

Let the service in question who needs the lock be called S1.

1. The S1 has a UUID as a static in-memory variable - `S1-UUID`.
2. First read the file `s3://bucket/locks/lock.json` with JSON format: `{UUID:'1-2-3-4' , createdTime:yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss-ms}`;
3. Does the `UUID` from JSON match with `S1-UUID`? yes? then you already have the lock. return true. If the string doesn't match...
4. was the lock created more than abort time? yes? Then move to `step  5`. No? then return saying you don't have the lock. return false.
5. Write `S1-UUID` and the current time to JSON and write it to `s3://bucket/lock/lock.json`
6. Wait for `250ms` --250 because I have never seen S3 latency to be more than 125ms; so taking double time to play safe. Read the `lock.json` again. Read the UUID from the JSON if the UUID matches `S1-UUID` then you get the lock. return true. If not return false.

For HTTP API calls I put the `abort time` as `2sec` (because HTTP SLA is 2sec to our APIs). For spark jobs with higher SLA, we put 2hrs --because the spark jobs take 2hrs to complete.